# bash find: path changes results with regex exclusion

Tags: bash, find

I want to exclude files from being reported by find using a regex. This however only seems to work if the path argument to find is a . (dot). As soon as I specify a path find does not return anything.

2 files in folder:

```
~/xtmp/testfind> ls
test1.tmp.txt   test1.txt
```

expected result by specifying the path as .

```
~/xtmp/testfind> find . -regex '.*txt.*' ! -regex '.*tmp.*' 
./test1.txt
```

with $PWD it does not find anything:

```
~/xtmp/testfind> find $PWD -regex '.*txt.*' ! -regex '.*tmp.*' 
~/xtmp/testfind>
```

dropping the ! regex it finds everything, so $PWD is correct:

```
~/xtmp/testfind> find $PWD -regex '.*txt.*' 
[...]/xtmp/testfind/test1.tmp.txt
[...]/xtmp/testfind/test1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path includes the string `tmp` (as `/xtmp/`), so the exclusion `! -regex '.*tmp.*'` always matches.  Negative matching of this kind is very difficult to do properly with regex; but in this case, you probably want to use a glob and `-name` (which matches only on the final pathname component and not the path leading to it).

```
find $PWD -name '*txt*' ! -name '*tmp*'
```

Comment: yes of course!!! my unit tests don't contain tmp as a path, thats why it works there.